# Published Expo app can't make network calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to publish an update to my app after upgrading the SDK from 27 to 32. The app works fine when I do `expo start` and run it on the emulator. But, when I do `expo publish` the finished app can't make network calls. Then, I realized you couldn't do `expo publish` if you update SDK (it still push the update somehow though), so I built the APK for Android. Thing is, the APK file nor the `expo publish` update work. It can't make network calls to pull user info for instance, but it works just fine with `expo start`.

Any ideas on what this could be or how can I troubleshoot it? I went back to the commit with SDK 27, built it and still, the app can't make network calls. It is also the first time I build this app from this computer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you are using the `__DEV__` constant somewhere?

Both the APK and the APK in the market are now on `__DEV__ == false`.

1. Are you sure that the app is not making calls?
2. Are you sure that they don't reach the server?
3. Are you sure that is not the server that is rejecting?
4. Did you try to make the calls outside of the app using a program like Postman?

Comment: The only time I use __DEV__ is for the developer tools. If I revert back to the previous build, it works just fine. However, the new one works on expo start but not when I publish. How is this possible? What can be different?

Comment: @user2876983 that sounds like something you must post on expo repository